# Searching multiple channels with Low Search, how do I direct the permalink to the correct template?

Tags: search, low-search

Might be having a brain fart on this one, but I'm using Low Search to search two channels and I cannot figure out how to direct them to the right templates. The results display, but I need the link to the entry to go to the correct page...

In Low's example they use this:

```
{comment_url_title_auto_path}
```

which is essentially replicating the permalink feature but without the option to direct it to a certain template. My if statements also don't seem to be working with {if collection=='xx'} either.

Comment: K, answered it myself using Lows' {low_search_collection_name} with if statements to direct the permalink.

Comment: If you have found a solution, remember to either accept an answer below, or post your own solution as an answer to help future visitors :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you goto Admin > Channels Administration > Channel > Edit Preferences and set the comment path to the proper URL (i.e. `{site_url}/blog/comments` ) you can use the `{comment_url_title_auto_path}` parameter also. It can be easier then doing conditionals for each channel you might be searching through.

Comment: I fully support this answer. Rather than using conditionals with the collection name, using the `{comment_url_title_auto_path}` variable (as long as it's configured correctly) is the easiest route.

Comment: Awesome, I've never seen bothered to set that before... Nice time saver!